# Angular js unable to access updated scope in directive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I created two directives and applied on element. when I alert ng-model in selectControlDir it get value in alert and from cbqControlDir I get undefined in alert.

I made some ajax call on load and on change in cbqControlDir where I am passing these value in url but getting undefined in url on page load.
**index.html**

```
<div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-5 control-label" for="VehicleOriginalCost">{{questions[$state.current.name].VehicleOriginalCost.QuestionData._text}}</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input type="text" id="VehicleOriginalCost" class="form-control" name="VehicleOriginalCost" ng-model="answers.VehicleOriginalCost" data-que-obj="questions[$state.current.name].VehicleOriginalCost.QuestionData" required text-control-dir cbq-dir number-only>
                        </div>                    
                    </div>
                    <span class="form-error" ng-show="submitted && DTOstep1.VehicleOriginalCost.$error.required">This field is required.</span>
                </div>
```

**controlDirective.js**

```
function textControlDir()
{
    return {
        transclude: true,
        restrict: 'A',
        priority: 100,
        scope: {
          ngModel: '=',
          queObj: '='
        },
       link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            if (angular.isUndefined(scope.ngModel))
            {
                scope.ngModel = scope.queObj._pageAttributes.defaultValue;
            }               
        }
    };
}

function cbqControlDir($http)
    {
        return {
            transclude: true,
            restrict: 'A',
            priority: 200,
            require: ngModel,
           link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        //http call 
       //url apc.php/ngModel          
            }
        };
    }
```

How to access updated scope value in directive?
[Plunker for code](https://plnkr.co/edit/aV65Nab9U9I6YlK2g4sY?p=preview)

Comment: Did you try using the `scope.$apply();` statement  after your `scope.ngModel = scope.queObj._pageAttributes.defaultValue;` assignment?

Comment: its not working. getting error.

Comment: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest